# ODBC command to update

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

What is the error in the below code, and how do I pass `karthik@domain.com` and `kars@domain.com` using forms?

```
string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=new_db;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;" + "OPTION=3";

OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email=karthik@domain.com WHERE email=kars@domain.com" , MyConnection);

MyConnection.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: Also can anyone tell me how to give the referral_email and email using forms?

Comment: no error but record not updated... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place single quotes around the email addresses.

Comment: Also how to give input to each using forms? i mean instead of karthik@domain.com and kars@domain.com I need to pass these values using forms

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create 
   SET referral_email='karthik@domain.com' WHERE email='kars@domain.com'",
   MyConnection);
```

If you need to parameterize that query, you can do something like:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_create
   SET referral_email=? WHERE email=?", MyConnection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@referral_email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "karthik@domain.com";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "kars@domain.com";
```

Comment: Also how to give input to each using forms? i mean instead of karthik@domain.com and kars@domain.com I need to pass these values using forms

Answer (score 1):

Your query has syntax errors:

```
UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email=karthik@domain.com WHERE email=kars@domain.com
```

there's no quotes around either email address. It should be

```
UPDATE awm_create SET referral_email='karthik@domain.com' WHERE email='kars@domain.com'
                                     ^--                ^--           ^--             ^--
```

Comment: Also how to give input to each using forms? i mean instead of karthik@domain.com and kars@domain.com I need to pass these values using forms

Answer (score 1):

My trick when faced with this type of error is to copy the SQL query from the code and execute it directly against the database using the database user interface. This way I ensure where the error lies. Yes you're missing the string delimiters and the query interface to MYSql would tell you that while the IDE interface only knows that there was an error.
If that step works then go up the chain to figure out what doesn't.